# Mysql apostrophes and quotes issue

Tags: php, mysql

I have some records in mysql database which contains some weird characters. When I checked those records in mysql then it shows a (square) for such characters. Also when I use a PHP command line script to show such records then such characters (square) are not visible on command line. It simply shows blank for such characters.

I think these characters are some special characters for apostrophes and quotes. We have already used the `mysql_real_escape()` function to escape special characters.

It shows squares in following examples:

> 1. it[]  good idea....
> 2. That[]  fine....
> 3. We don[] t have that...

Can you please let me know how to solve this issue? Does anyone else face such an issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had a lot of problems with that too. It all depends on the "magic_quotes_gpc" property that is configured in php. On some web host it is set to "on" and on some others it is not.

Try `quoted_printable_decode($value)` in the first case, and `str_replace("'", "''", $value)`

I'm pretty sure that there's a better function that deals will both cases, but for the moment that's the only approach that worked for me lol.